# Copy file from directory to another using cmd command

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I want to copy a file from sharing folder to another using cmd command ".bat file" 
the below code works normally with most files except MS Access files the "accde" extension so, please advise.

```
MKDIR "\\192.168.0.110\Attendance Sheet\JTA\events\events_media\SysFile"

XCopy /y/z "\\192.168.0.110\Attendance Sheet\JTA\events\events_media\db.accde" 

"\\192.168.0.110\Attendance Sheet\JTA\events\events_media\SysFile"
```

Comment: What error(s) do you get for that type of file?

Comment: nothing the batch runs normally but the file won`t be copied

Comment: i don`t know is it a permission from the administrator or something wrong in the code ? ..... if it is permission how shall i override that ?

Comment: Why using __xcopy__ for copying a single file and not __copy__? Do you have ever executed in a command prompt window `xcopy /?` and read help output by this command? For example if file `db.accde` has the hidden attribute set, you need the parameter `/H`. You should use a space between the options.

Comment: thanks /H works perfect but, the cmd window stays till the copy is done "the file has large size".... is there any way to hide it while coping the file

Comment: If you want to hide your batch, you should use a vbscript to launch it in hidden mode ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run this code to have the command execute in the background so that you can continue to work from the command line while it is running:

```
start /min xcopy /y /z "sourcefile" "destination"
```

Actually, the command is running in a minimized window of it's own - you can see it popping up in the taskbar. But from a user's perspective it's the same as running "in the background".

Comment: i will try it but, i have another question: i try "/D:m-d-y" but, doesn`t work i don`t want to copy the file every time i just want to copy it if there any modification done on it ...how shall i use it ?

Comment: Use the `/M` option with `xcopy` which looks at the 'modified' flag. Only if the file has been modified since last copied it will be copied and the 'archive' flag will be reset. You need some permissions on the source files to reset the flag, though. But you could get rid of the date selection ('/D').